# Mysql optimisation in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, optimization

I have some tables with ~10 millions rows.
Time of execution this query is about ~10 minutes:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    CONCAT_WS(', ', country.name, region.name, c.name) AS [text]
FROM city_name AS cn
    INNER JOIN city AS c 
        ON c.id = cn.city_id
    INNER JOIN country 
        ON country.id = cn.country_id
    INNER JOIN region 
        ON region.id = cn.region_id
WHERE cn.name LIKE '%:q%'
GROUP BY cn.city_id
LIMIT 50
```

But when i'm making two queries its executions about 5 seconds:

First one:

```
SELECT 
    city_id
FROM city_name
WHERE name LIKE '%:q%'
GROUP BY city_id
LIMIT 50
```

Second one:

```
SELECT
    c.id, 
    CONCAT_WS(', ',country.name,region.name,c.name) AS text
FROM city AS c
    INNER JOIN country 
        ON country.id = c.country_id
    INNER JOIN region 
        ON region.id = region_id
WHERE c.id IN (:ids)
```

How can I optimize it into one query?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked Explain plan

Comment: You're using `LIKE='%.....%'` which cannot use any index (as string indices do not index the entire string but rather a subset). Without knowing the purpose of that column I cannot make any exact recommendation but overall try to rewrite it as `LIKE='...%'` (prefixed).

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is fairly meaningless. Similarly, a LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried inner query like this.

```
    SELECT
    c.id, CONCAT_WS(', ',country.name,region.name,c.name) AS text
FROM
    city AS c
INNER JOIN
    country ON country.id = c.country_id
INNER JOIN
    region ON region.id = region_id
WHERE
    c.id IN (
        SELECT 
            city_id
        FROM
            city_name
        WHERE
            name LIKE '%:q%'
        GROUP BY
            city_id
        LIMIT 50
    )
```

Or try moving the filter `cn.name LIKE '%:q%'`  from where claus to ON claus of first JOIN

Answer (score 1):

I'm more well-versed in T-SQL, so forgive me if I mungle some syntax slightly. Hopefully the concept is clear.

```
SELECT
    c.id, CONCAT_WS(', ',country.name,region.name,c.name) AS text
FROM
    (SELECT city_id
    FROM city_name
    WHERE name LIKE '%:q%'
    GROUP BY city_id) AS c
INNER JOIN
    country ON country.id = c.country_id
INNER JOIN
    region ON region.id = region_id
WHERE
    c.id IN (:ids)
```

Joining each table then doing an expensive filter at the end means it needs to act on a very large number of results. If you do the expensive filter on just the city_name table first, then join to that, it cuts down on the number of rows involved in the joins dramatically.

YMMV, but this strategy, while not pretty, has worked well for me in the past. In T-SQL, I'd also usually either make the first result into a temp table or a CTE, but I'm not sure how that works in MySql, so consider some additional research into those areas for added performance.

Answer (score -1):

"Normalize, but don't overnormalize".

Normalizing city+country+region is *usually* an example of overnormalization.  Recommend having a single table with those 3 columns, rather than a 3-table `JOIN`.  Also recommend using the standard 2-letter `country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`.